# Role of specifying the header in a python request as the user-agent }

Tags: python, python-requests, header

Can I please know what does specifying the header in a python requests as a user-agent taken from a html webpage actually do?

```
import requests
URL = 'https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/its-only-the-himalayas_981/index.html'
r = requests.get(URL,headers={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36'
            })
```

Comment: It tells the website what browser you are using. This used to be vital in the days when every browser used a different, nonstandard, version of HTML. It is common for browsers to lie. Some websites used to use this to detect automated scraping. But It is so easy to spoof that they now use other means.

Answer (score 1):

[image: User Agent String]

The `User-Agent` request header is a characteristic string that lets servers and network peers identify the application, operating system, vendor, and/or version of the requesting user agent.

**Syntax**

```
User-Agent: <product> / <product-version> <comment>
```

**Common format for web browsers**

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (<system-information>) <platform> (<platform-details>) <extensions>
```

**Directives**

`<product>`
A product identifier — its name or development codename.

`<product-version>`
Version number of the product.

`<comment>`
Zero or more comments containing more details; sub-product information, for example.

**Version**
As their name suggests, version tokens represent a browser's version. Three popular web browsers are shown in the following list.

| Name | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Chrome/41.0.2228.0 | Chrome web browser running on version 41.0.2228.0 |
| Firefox/40.1 | Firefox web browser running on version 40.1 |
| MSIE11 | Internet Explorer web browser running on version 11 |

**Platform**
Platform token are used to help the web server identify which operating system is being used. Examples of some of the platforms are given below.

| Name | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2 | Macintosh OS X version 10_11_2 running on Intel CPU |
| Linux x86_64 | Linux running on Intel CPU and 64-bit processor |
| Windows NT 6.3 | Windows 8.1 |

**Other tokens**
A user agent string can also include numerous other tokens that exist. Although the list is quite large, here are a few popular other tokens to mention.

| Name | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Tablet PC | Tablet services are installed. This token is also accompanied by a version number |
| AppleWebKit | Provides a set of core classes to display web content in windows |
| Like Gecko | Mozilla-based rendering engine |
| KHTML | Konquerer-based rendering engine |

**References :**

[MDN web docs](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent#syntax)
[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent)
[keycdn](https://www.keycdn.com/support/user-agent-string)